# Change frame of view when status bar height will be changed?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uistatusbar

I want to change the position of UIImageView and button in view controller when status bar height will be increased.

I have changed the view frame by comparing status bar height and I also know that below method will be called when status bar frame will be changed but it will be called in delegate.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)oldStatusBarFrame
```

but I want to change position of image view & button in view controller so how can I do that?

Comment: i found the solutions by implementing below method: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeframe) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You can create a public method in your view to change the position when one of those methods trigger, something like:

```
-(void)changePosition {
myImageView.frame = CGRectMake(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, myImageView.frame.size. width, myImageView.frame.size.height) 

myButton.frame = CGRectMake(newPosition.x, newPosition.y, myButton.frame.size. width, myButton.frame.size.height) 
}
```

To make it public, create it in the .h file, something like:

```
@interface MyView : UIViewController {
}

-(void)changePosition;
@end
```

And then you call from your delegate:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application willChangeStatusBarFrame:(CGRect)newStatusBarFrame{

[myView changePosition];

}
```

Comment: i think for that the method would be class method like which should have + instead of - ahead of that method...

Comment: If you put + you would do a static method

Comment: thanx but i found another solution by implementing below method:                                           [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(changeframe) name:UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification object:nil];

Answer (score 0):

You can observe **UIApplicationWillChangeStatusBarFrameNotification** or **UIApplicationDidChangeStatusBarFrameNotification**.